# Replace a hive partition from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

Is there a way I can replace (an existing) a hive partition from a Spark program? Replace only the latest partition, rest of the partitions remains the same.

Below is the idea which I am trying to work upon,

We get transnational data from our RDBMS systems coming into HDFS every min. There will be a spark program (running every 5 or 10 min) which reads the data, performs the ETL and writes the output into a Hive Table. 
Since overwriting entire hive table would be huge, 
we would like to overwrite the hive table for today's partition only. 
End of Day the source and destination partitions would be changed to next day.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know the hive table location, append the currentdate to location as your table is partitioned on date and overwrite the hdfs path.

```
df.write.format(source).mode("overwrite").save(path)
```

`Msck repair hive table`

once it is completed